# Using docker build in gitlab CI/CD can't resolve names

Tags: docker, gitlab, debian

I want to build a docker image in a gitlab CI/CD pipeline. I've configured the `docker:latest` image with the `docker:dind` service. In the `script` section I have a call to `docker build ...`

Everything seems to be working OK but when the build starts the container can't resolve names. In the `Dockerfile` I have some `RUN apt-get install ...` to add some packages but I always get:

```
Step 2/10 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 91026c489af2
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
```

The gitlab runner is using the docker executor.

Comment: I think you should see this [article](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-the-docker-executor-with-the-docker-image-docker-in-docker).

Comment: I've read it but can't find anything related or that can solve my problem. I think it's probably docker related and I don't have much docker experience so I can't see how to fix it.

Comment: Seems like a bad runner configuration or bad host issue. Are you running this on gitlab.com shared runners or a self-hosted runner? If self-hosted, can you share your runner configuration and provide some information about how the host is configured (operating system, version of docker, etc)? Can you reach those sources in your job e.g. using `curl` outside the docker build?

Comment: @sytech I'm running on a self-hosted runner. Config is here: https://pastebin.com/PyvmsV1m. Docker info: https://pastebin.com/36Rk4NGc. Outside `docker build` I can reach them without any issues. Only happens inside the build.